# Statistical counting in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics

I have a set of five letters A..E. I would like to combine them in groups of 3 with no letters repeated but I'm clueless about where to begin.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html (but bear in mind that package/library/other off-site resource recommendations are off-topic for SO)

Comment: Do you have to extract 3 letters? Otherwise I don't understand what you mean

Comment: This sounds like [n choose k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) - "A combination is a way of selecting members from a grouping, such that (unlike permutations) the order of selection does not matter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
s = set('ABCDE')
```

---

## Single extraction

If you only need one extraction use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from random import sample
print sample(s, 3)
# ['E', 'C', 'A']
```

---

## All the combinations

If you want all the combinations use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
print list(combinations(s, 3))
# [('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'E', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'E'), ('C', 'B', 'D'), ('C', 'E', 'D'), ('B', 'E', 'D')]
```

---

## All the permutations

If you want all the combinations use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
print list(permutations(s, 3))
# [('A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'E', 'C'), ('A', 'E', 'B'), ('A', 'E', 'D'), ('A', 'D', 'C'), ('A', 'D', 'B'), ('A', 'D', 'E'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'E'), ('C', 'A', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'E'), ('C', 'B', 'D'), ('C', 'E', 'A'), ('C', 'E', 'B'), ('C', 'E', 'D'), ('C', 'D', 'A'), ('C', 'D', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'E'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'E'), ('B', 'A', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'E'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'E', 'A'), ('B', 'E', 'C'), ('B', 'E', 'D'), ('B', 'D', 'A'), ('B', 'D', 'C'), ('B', 'D', 'E'), ('E', 'A', 'C'), ('E', 'A', 'B'), ('E', 'A', 'D'), ('E', 'C', 'A'), ('E', 'C', 'B'), ('E', 'C', 'D'), ('E', 'B', 'A'), ('E', 'B', 'C'), ('E', 'B', 'D'), ('E', 'D', 'A'), ('E', 'D', 'C'), ('E', 'D', 'B'), ('D', 'A', 'C'), ('D', 'A', 'B'), ('D', 'A', 'E'), ('D', 'C', 'A'), ('D', 'C', 'B'), ('D', 'C', 'E'), ('D', 'B', 'A'), ('D', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'B', 'E'), ('D', 'E', 'A'), ('D', 'E', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'B')]
```

---

#### Everything else

*Be more specific in your questions and check the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) page, it has all the answers.*

Comment: why would you make a set from a unique list of elements and permutations have repeat

Comment: Just because the OP said he has a set made of those letters.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, check out itertools.combinations

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.combinations#itertools.combinations